# Using formulas with stock data type in MS excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office365

I just recently started to be interested in trading crypto currencies. I made excel workbook to help me track loss/profit and other indicators. I bumped into a problem when using Excel stock data type. For example I have

```
    A          B
1   Crypto     Price
2   BTC/EUR    42 0000
3   BTC/USD    57 000
```

Now I want to use LEFT(A2;3) to extract "BTC" from cell A2 to tell it is bitcoin. The problem is that I cannot directly work like this with this datatype. When using any kind of formula I'm getting #VALUE error.

Any advice on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use `Left` on the `Ticker symbol` field:

```
=LEFT(A2.[Ticker symbol];3)
```

[image]